# How to use widgets in Django Crisp Forms

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms, django-widget

I am using Django Crispy forms and its FormHelper. In my FormHelper class  i want that one of the field should use widgets. The reason for using widget is that i want to populate a date picker in one of the field.

Using the Field, i am able to populate the DatePicker in my updated_date by identifying the css_class. But i want to give DatePicker a format and theme (attrs). How will i be able to do that?

forms.py

```
class DeviceFilterFormHelper(FormHelper):
    # form_class = "form form-inline"

    form_id = "Device-search-form"
    form_method = "GET"
    form_tag = True
    html5_required = True
    layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div('name', css_class="col-md-6"),
            Div('location', css_class="col-md-6"),
            css_class='row'
        ),
        Div(
            Div('phone_number', css_class="col-md-6"),
            Div(Field('updated_date', css_class="date-time-picker")),
            css_class='row'
            ),
        FormActions(
            Submit("submit", ("Search"), css_class="col-md-5"),
            css_class="col-8  text-right align-self-center",
        ),
    )
```

Below is the widget along with its attributes which i want to use in the FormHelper.

```
updated_date = forms.DateInput(attrs={
                                               'required': True,
                                               'class': 'date-time-picker',
                                               'data-options': '{"format":"Y-m-d H:i", "timepicker":"true"}'

                                           }),
```

I just can't figure out how will i be using the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this in your `FormHelper`-based class, instead what I usually do is to hook into the `__init__` method of the *form* class, and that's where I'll perform any alterations to the form/layout/widgets, etc. Something along these lines might work for you:

```
class DeviceFilterFormHelper(FormHelper):
    ... # no changes to your class/code from above


class DeviceFilterForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = DeviceFilterFormHelper(self)
        self.fields['updated_date'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={
                'required': True,
                'class': 'date-time-picker',
                'data-options': '{"format":"Y-m-d H:i", "timepicker":"true"}'
            })
```

Note that this technique isn't tied to Crispy - you can do this with any Django form, whether you're using Crispy to render it or not.

Comment: That i know but i wanted it to be in my FormHelper.

Comment: I can appreciate that, but the `FormHelper` class doesn't offer any sort of initialization hooks, nor does it have any connection to your form class's `fields` propertym so I don't think there's any way to do this, other than in the forms init method... or anytime after that! For instance, you could do some similar code inside of your actual view function, when you instantiate the form. Just start hacking at form.fields['updated_date'] before the template is rendered.